# Windows Service Tick ElapsedEventArgs is never called

Tags: c#, service, timer, windows-services

I tried to deploy one service which works great in local to the production server. But on this server, the ElapsedEventHandler seems to never call my method Tick()

I have read other similar threads as
[First Windows Service - timer seems not to tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805159/first-windows-service-timer-seems-not-to-tick)
or
[Timer tick event is not called in windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561479/timer-tick-event-is-not-called-in-windows-service)
but i couldn't have any answer to my problem :/

I also tried to use _timer.Enabled=1 instead of _timer.Start (no incidence normally but still tried) and also tried to reinstall service a couple of times.

I use the Timer from Class System.Timers.
here is my code :

```
static void Main()
{
    var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new SynchronizeEvents() 
    };
    #if DEBUG
    servicesToRun.LoadServices();
    #else
    ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    #endif
}
```

and

```
public partial class SynchronizeEvents : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();//Nlog
    private Timer _timer;//From Class System.Timers

    private readonly DbSetName _db = new DbSetName ();

    private static readonly Dictionary<Employee, otherStuff> Subscriptions = new Dictionary<Employee, otherStuff>();
    public SynchronizeEvents()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _logger.Trace("Service Start");
        _timer = new Timer(5000) { AutoReset = false };//Same problem without AutoReset = false
        _timer.Elapsed += Tick;
        _timer.Start();
        _logger.Trace("End OnStart");
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        _logger.Trace("OnShutdown");
        _timer.Stop();
        base.OnShutdown();
    }

    protected void Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
    {
        _logger.Trace("Tick");
        _timer.Stop();
        Compute();
        _timer.Start();
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _logger.Trace("OnStop");
    }
```

Everything works great while on DebugMode and also on local computer in Release mode, but when i install it on production server the only logs i got are :

> 2014-09-08 16:35:57.1929 TRACE Service Start
>
> 2014-09-08 16:35:57.2085 TRACE End OnStart

i also got this when i stop the service...

> 2014-09-08 16:40:52.4072 TRACE End OnStop

Comment: Check your windows event viewer logs, see if there is any exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Service System.Timers.Timer not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466597/windows-service-system-timers-timer-not-firing)

Comment: @Habib just learned that exists :)
The only events that i see for my service are of type "Information" and the detail is "Service started successfully."

Comment: What does Compute do?

Comment: 1 ) when is OnShutdown called ?
2) have you tried a shorter interval ?

Comment: @SteveWellens Whatever, it's never called.
I never got the log "_logger.Trace("Tick");"
It actually do some changes on database.

Comment: @eranotzap OnShutdown seems to be never called as i never see it in logs (According to the documententation, it's called when the system shuts down.) I tried an interval of 500, it didn't change anything.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i'm actually trying to use System.Threading.Timers even if it requires some refactoring :/

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov when using System.Threading.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer, it's exactly the same (Working on Local/Test server but not on production) :/

Comment: What's the difference between the machines?  Running same .NET version?

Comment: @Zer0 Yes, same version. I just found out what the problem was. One DLL was missing on this server but no exception raised for that :/

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got to apologize to Steve Wellens, he was right to ask about what Compute do.
The problem was related to Compute().
It had some code which required a DLL which was missing.
I don't know why _logger.Trace("Tick"); wasn't called and no Exception was triggered :/
I had to comment my program line per line to find out where the problem came from...

Comment: An exception was generated.  Subscribe to `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and you'll see it.  This catch-all tends to save a lot of time.